# Última posição de uma string

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
 var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
     var txt = elements[i].innerHTML.replace('Estoque1', 'Estoque Vencido');
    }
```

Ele captura todas as tags de página, e altera a palavra Estoque1 para Estoque Vencido. Preciso fazer um código que ele **apague** tudo que estiver abaixo da palavra "Estoque Vencido", depois de alterado a palavra. No Caso, se fosse em delphi eu usaria o `lastpos`, agora no JavaScript não faço ideia, alguém pode me ajudar ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com a utilização de expressões regulares pode-se fazer isso:

```js
var txt = "Foo Bar Estoque1 Baz Poo Par Paz...";
txt = txt.replace(/Estoque1(.*)/, "Estoque Vencido");
// => Foo Bar Estoque Vencido
```

A função `laspos`(*ou* [`LastDelimiter`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SysUtils.LastDelimiter)) do Delphi pode ser considerada equivalente ao [`lastIndexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf) do Javascript.

```js
var elementos = document.querySelectorAll('body *');
for (var indice = 0; indice < elementos.length; indice++)
{
   var txt = elementos[indice].innerHTML;
   var last = txt.lastIndexOf('Estoque1'); 
   if(txt.indexOf('Estoque1') > -1)
   {
      txt = txt.substring(0, last) + "Estoque Vencido" + txt.substring(last + txt.length);
      elementos[indice].innerHTML = txt;
   }
}
```

[`Fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/AsdQL/)

Comment: no seu caso, ele apagou a pagina inteira, e deixou somente a palavra Estoque Vencido aparecendo. Eu preciso que ele apague tudo pra "BAIXO" ou "SOMENTE APÓS" o estoque vencido, pra cima dele ele deixa tudo normal, entende ?

Comment: Obrigado como sempre pela atenção @Sunstreaker, me diz uma coisa, como seria uma página inteira em HTML, e eu não sei se vai estar dentro de uma tag div, body etc.....tem como eu fazer usando FOR ? pra ele procurar pela pagina toda ? exemplo: var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {  dessa forma ?

Comment: perfeito o script, deu certo....Obrigado amigo...

Comment: Se puder me esclarecer ainda nesse topico, depois que eu apagar a determinada palavra para baixo, como eu faço para inserir uma imagem dessa palavra pra baixo ? é possível ? sei que no Delphi eu usaria o comando Insert.

Comment: @user7605 Eu acredito que seja possível sim, veja essa [pergunta](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12287856/insert-image-object-into-html). Basta adaptá-lo.

Comment: Obrigado @Sunstreaker!

Answer (score 2):

Você poderia utilizar a função `.slice()` do JavaScript, então seu código ficaria assim:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('body *');
 for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
     var txt = elements[i].innerHTML;

     //Só dispara as alterações caso o conteúdo contenha a palavra "Estoque1"
     if(txt.indexOf('Estoque1') > -1){
         txt = txt.replace('Estoque1', 'Estoque Vencido');
         txt = txt.slice(0,15);
         elements[i].innerHTML = txt;
     }
 }
```

Eu também subistitui `.getElementsByTagName()` por `.querySelectorAll()` para melhor funcionamento.

Exemplo: **[`FIDDLE`](http://jsfiddle.net/qc3SX/)**

Comment: nesse caso que você postou, ele altera todas as palavras Estoque1 que existem na página, eu preciso diferente. Depois que ele encontrar a palavra Estoque1, ele troque por Estoque Vencido, e tudo que estiver APÓS a palavra estoque vencido ele apaga tudo da página, entendeu ?

Comment: Mas é isto que ele faz, só que relativo ao elemento em que se encontra a palavra. Ou você quer que ele delete todos os outros elementos no DOM abaixo da palavra "Estoque1"?

Comment: quero que ele todos os elementos, abaixo da palavra Estoque1, tudo....que tiver no html.